# jQuery commands not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am working on a website for a project of mine, and I am trying to incorporate some simple jQuery commands. They don't seem to be working. Please read through and let me know if I am missing something.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="button"> <a href="index.htm" class="a-top">Home</a></div>
<div class="button"> <a href="aboutus.htm" class="a-top">About us</a></div>
<div class="button"> <a href="contactus.htm" class="a-top">Contact us</a></div>

<div class="button-right" id="businesses"> <a href="forbusinesses.htm" class="a-top">For
businesses</a></div>
<div class="button-right"> <a href="forusers.htm" class="a-top">For users</a></div>


<div class="fluid-margin">
<div class="orange-body">



        <div class="fake-header">
        <img src="http://i879.photobucket.com/albums/ab358/dylanhusted/bulletnlogotranssmall_zpsa04c3fed .png" id="logo"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="landing-page">

<div id="call-to-action">
    <img src="https://scontent-b-lga.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/1608452_3821343707689_2110853534_n.jpg?oh=ab5ebfd5dce574e97a43e9a7c0739583&oe=52D0F2AC" id="learn-button"/>
</div>
<img src="https://scontent-b-lga.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/v/1551908_3821359708089_1101636385_o.jpg?oh=aa19a9ac5f5b5e4f3cf704858482803d&oe=52D11726"id="line"/>
</div>



<div class="footer">
    <a href="index.htm" class="a-footer">Home</a>
    <a href="aboutus.htm" class="a-footer">About Us</a>
    <a href="contactus.htm" class="a-footer">Contact Us</a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#landing-page {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom: 40%;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

#line {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.orange-body {
    width: 70%;
    z-index: -3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: auto;
}
.fluid-margin {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:8%;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.fake-header {
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    z-index: -0;
}

#logo {
    width: 28%;
    height: 63%;
    margin-top: .7%;
    margin-left: 14%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
    color: #8d8d8d;
    font-size: 110%;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').mouseover(function() {
    (this).css("color", "#dfdbd8");
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in your console window?

Comment: If this is all your HTML you are not including the jquery.js

Comment: `$(this).css("color", "#dfdbd8");` you forget `$` And don't hesitate to open your console ;)

Comment: Jason: No errors were in the console window

Comment: Luis: I called the script.js file in the beginning of my HTML. Is that not enough?

Comment: A.Wolff: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I corrected it but I'm still not getting a change in the color of my text when I put my mouse on the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
 $('a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("color", "#dfdbd8");
  });
```

**So I am an idiot!**

In your css add:

```
a:hover{color:#dfdbd8}
```

I didn't read close enough, and you dont actually require JS to do it!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I corrected it but I'm still not getting a change in the color of my text when I put my mouse on the hyperlinks.

Comment: hard refresh your page, might be some cache, still serving old css.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I could do it in my CSS file! Thanks for the help.